# Custom user start-up configuration/variable?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a web extension that reads from a dynamically generated value for a system upon startup.  The value is stored in a text file that can be read by anyone on the system.  However based on my research, it looks like it is not recommended to create an extension that has access to the user's filesystem due to security concerns.

With that said, I was hoping to create a script that takes the dynamic value and stores it as part of some user/system configuration file for that extension in Chrome at system startup.  However it looks like doing that may cause Chrome to disable the extension due to integrity issues.  Is there any way to declare some sort of system global variable using some sort of configuration file for a Chrome extension to read from?

Native messaging appears to be a way to do this but looks like it might be a bit much for trying to read a single "global" variable for my extension.

What are some other ways to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can read from `file://` URL set by a user. The user would have to enable file URLs on chrome://extensions page though.

Comment: Does that mean the user would have to specify the specific file URL?  Could we specify a static location?

Comment: Well if you think you know the exact URL, go ahead.